# Thread safe and "Collection was mutated while being enumerated"

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, performance, crash

I have a class "Ad" where I set a static variable inside my Ad.m :

```
static NSDictionary *citiesDict = nil; // class variable
```

and in the same file I have implemented a class method that basically load a plist file of the name of cities with their index numbers if it's not already loaded and finally convert the number value passed as paramater to the name of the city :

```
+(NSString *) cityFromNumberValue:(NSString *)cityNumberValue
{   
    // load the cities from the plist file named "cities" if it's not already loaded
    if (!citiesDict)
    {  
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cities" ofType:@"plist"];

       citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
       NSLog(@"loading plist");

    }

NSLog(@"will return value");
NSArray *temp = [ citiesDict allKeysForObject:cityNumberValue];  
NSString *key = [temp lastObject]; 
return key ;
}
```

and always in the same file I have implement an init method to convert a Dictionary to an Ad object where It uses the Class method  +cityFromNumberValue:cityNumberValue :

```
-(id) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionay
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
    // convert the number to name of city
    self.departureCity= [Ad cityFromNumberValue:[dictionay objectForKey:@"ad_villedepart"]]; 
    self.arrivalCity=   [Ad cityFromNumberValue:[dictionay objectForKey:@"ad_villearrivee"]]; 
    }
return self;
}
```

And I also have inside the same file a method to fetch Ads from a web service where it calls the method +cityFromNumberValue:cityNumberValue: inside a for loop :

```
+(NSDictionary *) fetchAdOfPage : (NSInteger) page PerPage : (NSInteger) perPage
{
    NSMutableArray *  adsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   ...... 
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:url];

// convert the new fetchted dictionnaries of Ads to an Ad objects

for (NSMutableDictionary *dictAd in array) 
{ 
  // convertion using the designated initializer

    Ad *ad = [[Ad alloc]initWithDictionary:dictAd]; 
    [adsArray addObject:ad]; 

    }
      ....
    return dictFinal ;
}
```

and somewhere else from mu controller I call this fetch methode like this :

```
 // do request on async thread
        dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{

            NSDictionary * dict = [Ad fetchAdOfPage:currentPage PerPage:kAdsPerPage];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                .....
            });
        });

        dispatch_release(fetchQ);
```

now my problem is that last time when I run the app inside the simulator I got an error "Collection was mutated while being enumerated" and it points to the line :

```
 NSArray *temp = [ citiesDict allKeysForObject:cityNumberValue];
```

but I got this error for the first time , I didn't get it before and I use the same code for more than three months and everything is ok , and I can't even reproduce the same error again !  after putting a NSLog to see what is happen I always get :

```
2013-05-21 19:39:20.141 myApp[744:3b03] loading plist
2013-05-21 19:39:20.151 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.151 myApp[744:3b03] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.152 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.153 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.154 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.153 myApp[744:3b03] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.155 myApp[744:6303] will return value
```

but one time I got :

```
2013-05-21 19:39:20.141 myApp[744:3b03] loading plist
2013-05-21 19:39:20.142 myApp[744:6303] loading plist
2013-05-21 19:39:20.151 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.151 myApp[744:3b03] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.152 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.153 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.154 myApp[744:6303] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.153 myApp[744:3b03] will return value
2013-05-21 19:39:20.155 myApp[744:6303] will return value
```

the app didn't crash but there is a strange "loading plist" twice since I have checked using the if statement ! so I guess that there is two threads have entered :

```
if (!citiesDict)
```

at the same time , and then both of them hav set the citiesDict Dictionary and since this dictionary can be used in

```
 [ citiesDict allKeysForObject:cityNumberValue];
```

just after the if statement that can cause the crash "Collection was mutated while being enumerated" , can this be the real senario ?

since I can't reproduce the error again I Wonder if adding :

```
   @synchronized(citiesDict)
    {
        citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSLog(@"loading plist");
    }
```

can fix that issue ? have you any suggestion to better implement a safer implementation and how we avoid in general the "Collection was mutated while being enumerated" error when we are obliged to work with the same Array from different threads , and can just reading the content of an array from a different threads causes a problem or the problem is just when writing at the same time ? thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with static objects, the best practice is to use the dispatch_once, this will ensure you the code is only executed once, giving you complete thread safety

It's also a good practice to have a getter method for your static objects

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getCitiesDict {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static NSDictionary *citiesDict = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cities" ofType:@"plist"];

        citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    });

    return citiesDict;
}
```

To access it, just go like this

```
[[OwnerClass getCitiesDict] valueForKey:@"key"]; // OwnerClass is the name of the class where this is defined
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but should I test if it's already set before I load the plist, to avoid that I keep load it all the time I call the getter ? or I will check from where I will call the getter by doing `if(!citiesDict)` ?

Comment: No need to check. The dispatch_once block is executed only once in the lifetime of the app, meaning the citiesDict will only be created once, and will ever after be alive and ready. Just call [self getCitiesDict] and you'll be good to go

Comment: Thank you again for your replay, just if you don't mind a last question, actually there is other class methodes that deal with cities and they need that same dictionary and they test if it's not loaded they load it from the plist they have this code and they can be executed in the same time : 
    `if (!citiesDict)
    {   
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cities" ofType:@"plist"];
        citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    }`

is it safe and can I face any problem after implementing the getter solution with dispatch_once ?

Comment: It is safe, we use it in our application that has been in the store for over 3 years. If you need to access the dictionary from outside, you will need to define the `+ (NSDictionary *)getCitiesDict;` in your header file. This way, you will only load it once, even if it is accessed from multiple places in your app. If you want more information about the obj-c dispatchers, I suggest you look up the documentation, they're pretty standard, although not very pretty to look at. Good luck :)

Comment: It works without any problem :) but the thing that I didn't understand is that we declared the variable `static NSDictionary *citiesDict = nil;` inside the method and it's still be accesible outside and from other objects anytime the application is running can you please explain to me how it works , especially the scoop of variables declared like in you solution , thank you in advance

Comment: Glad it works :D I don't know if there is any official documentation, but I can tell you this: you can't change the object reference from outside, because the variable is private (it's like a readonly property), however it's a mutable dictionary so you can edit it's key/values without problems. This is a fairly common practice in iOS. An example is `NSFileManager`, if you look up the class reference, `defaultManager` returns a sharedInstance, it doesn't create a new object every time you call it.

Answer (score 2):

@synchronized(citiesDist) is not the best but should fix your problem... anyway in my opinion the best way to initialize once a variable in a thread safe enviroment is using the GCD in this way:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
dispatch_once(&once, ^{
    citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"loading plist");
});
```

Comment: So I guess the code should be :   

 `if (!citiesDict)
 {    

   static dispatch_once_t once;
   dispatch_once(&once, ^{

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cities" ofType:@"plist"];


    citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc ]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"loading plist"); 
  });
}`

Comment: you don't need to do the check if (!citiesDict) {} , the block will be dispatched only once

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. In order to implement thread-safe loading of that array from within the same method, synchronize it and put a null check in it:

```
@synchronized(citiesDict)
{
    if (!citiesDict)
    {
        citiesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSLog(@"loading plist");
    }
}
```

Put that above code into a function that you call before you read the array. Essentially you want to avoid reading the array while it is loading.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is it ok if there is other class methodes that load the plist if it's not set and just read it ?